# Calling notifyDataSetChanged() from inside Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

My implementation of `ArrayAdapter` is such that it listens for changes in the under lying data. So any changes in the data, the adapter is notified and it calls the `notifydataSetChanged()`

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements ObjectStateListener {

    @Override
    public void onObjectStateChanged() {
        /*Call appropriate functions as the underlying data as changed.
        A good way of doing that would be to retrieve only the positions of the filtered values
        so that the original dataholder can be used but display only certain indices
         */
        Log.v(TAG, "FilterCriteria changed. Trigger fired");
        this.filterPositions = Helper().getFilteredPositions(filterCriteria, mAppartments);

        Log.v(TAG, "CALLING NOTIFYDATASETCHANGED()...");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.v(TAG, "FINISHED CALLING NOTIFY DATASET CHANGED");

    }
}
```

In the above code the function `onObjectStateChanged()` is called whenever there is change in the data and in turn it calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`. To test if the `onObjectStateChanged()` is called correctly, I have put a bunch of Log statements as you can see. All those logs appear in logcat. But `getView()` is not getting called after calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` and hence the listview is not getting refreshed.
Why is this happening? `notifyDataSetChanged()` is supposed to ensure that `getView()` gets called and the new data is reflected in the ListView right?

Definition of `ObjectStateChangeListener`

```
public interface ObjectStateListener {

    public void onObjectStateChanged();
    public void listenForStateChange(Object o);
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `onObjectStateChanged` from UI thread?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 : Yes, if I hadn't it would throw an exception.

Comment: What's the definition of your ObjectStateListener?

Comment: @Leog : How does that matter? Anyway I have pasted the definition of ObjectStateListener.

Comment: @Ashwin: where you are adding,removing data from Adapter? because `notifyDataSetChanged()` method only work when any change made in data-structure which from which `getCount` method return size of data and `getItem` method return current item using index

Comment: @Ashwin I just want to make sure you don't have a notifyDataSetChanged method  in your ObjectStateListener, I have made this mistake before. Obviously you don't have this mistake.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : Actually, I am not making any change to the data as such. I am only making changes in the positions of the data that have to be displayed. It's like filtering. So, whenever there is a change in the filter, I am calling notifyDataSetChanged() so that only a portion of the data (that satisfies the filter criteria) is displayed.

Comment: Oh... I was wondering this. I guess you ll have to reset the list view adapter using `setAdapter` because adapter is not changing exactly (i mean its size). Not sure thought. You can give it a try.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 : So, you mean to say that notifyDataSetChanged() is optimised to not call getView in case the underlying data does not change?

Comment: Yeah I think so... This is what it says http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29

Comment: @Rohit5k2 : The setAdapter is not working.

Comment: Well then you can try redrawing the listview using `invalidateViews()`

Comment: @Rohit5k2 : Nope, still does not work. It seems to work if I call notifyDataSetChanged() from outside the adapter. But I don't understand how that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deleting or inserting a new value on the list then whenever there is change in adapter list notifystatechange() will be called so     just after inserting or deleting the value call notifystatechange () it will refresh the listview.

Comment: @Pranav: you are just stating where to user the method, not exactly solving the problem. Not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to stop using notifyDataSetChanged() on my AutoCompleTextViews as they're not refreshing either. I just keep a local copy of the adapter and then reset it with the new dataset when it's changed.

Be sure your ArrayAdapter is set to notify on change (it is by default), and you technically shouldn't even need to make that call to notifyDataSetChanged() based on the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

First update the data where you have kept it's reference in the adapter and then call the notifyDataSetChanged(). You will have to pass in the new data as well.

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 This should not have been a comment.